Did an aircraft have to turn back because a mother left her baby in the terminal?
In March of 2019 there were reports in the news that a Saudi airliner had to return to the airport when a mother reported to cabin crew that she had forgotten her baby in the terminal building. The quoted flight number was SV832.
Flight emergency: I forgot my baby at the airport
This has also been reported elsewhere however I am skeptical that this is real, mainly because the supposed "viral video" no longer exists on youtube. What might be the same video may still exist elsewhere.
Is there any credible evidence that this, or anything similar, happened? Credible evidence would be sources such as an aviation regulator incident report or such-like, rather than multiple stories by mainstream media outlets basically quoting each other.

And nobody noticed a baby left in the boarding area? The conversation “a passenger left her baby in the terminal and refuses to continue the flight” ... “Ok, head back to the gate...” suggests the aircraft had not actually taken off.

I get zero relevant google hits for '"sv822" "baby" "return" 2019' (just one other than this q, and unrelated).  '"sv822" "baby" return' returns no news results at all.

Here is the supposed radio conversation. "Sir, confirm you are returning back to the gate." This means the aircraft was still on the tarmac. And then "Ok, return to the gate".

@WeatherVane good that a video still survives. But that is absolutely not "ATC" (as was reported) - quite possibly a dispatcher. But also soooo very easy to mockup/fake for "news". There's absolutely no way to verify that video is what it says it is.

So if the radio convo was a fake, they did a poor job of supporting the story of a pilot who turned back mid flight. And if is was a real convo, then the aircraft was still taxiing, which would explain the urgency in the pilot's voice, knowing he would be committed to take-off very soon.

@WeatherVane exactly. If I had to guess Id say it was a real story, but it was the latter case, and the usual sloppy reporting on anything technical (ie/ "it had taken off" as a misunderstanding of "it had begun taxying out to the runway"). Still, there's no actual evidence either way.

One of the reports did actually say "it is unclear whether they had taken off" but I can't find that one now. The others just plagiarised, so it's still unclear what the source of the story is (or who recorded the radio traffic).

@WeatherVane If an unattended backpack had been left, it would have been noticed within a few minutes. A baby on the other hand would not necessitate evacuating the terminal.

@doneal24 are you suggesting that someone may have investigated the unattended bundle, said "It's only a baby" and left it?

The story as reported by The Sun includes the video still, and also has a picture of the flight from a flight radar website showing a 54 minute delay, but remarking that it's unclear whether the flight had actually taken off before returning to the gate.

Not impossible, but impossible to confirm to the degree requested.
While there's plenty of reason to be suspicious given that there's an identical event described by an article dated September 18th, 2023 - one which is an obvious product of ChatGPT - credible journalistic sources including The Guardian picked up the story - and they have the resources to verify/validate the contents of the video. SVA832 (I'm a US-based VATSIM controller so I use the FAA callsign instead of the ICAO) is a regular schedule service between Jeddah and Sepang. If a prank, or fake news situation, running down that detail is a bit more work than I typically see - they could have just said "a Saudi flight" or whatever.
It is all but certain that the aircraft did not take off. As discussed in comments, the request was a return to the gate. The only ATC that could have given that instruction would have been a ground controller, and since no taxi instruction is given, we can determine they hadn't yet entered a movement area.  For a fake news bit, you'd actually want the scenario to be that the aircraft successfully took off.
The radio conversation, therefore, must be with the ramp controller - who are airline employees as often as not, are not held to the same phraseology standards, and aren't on the frequencies that proper ATC communicates on.
People do forget all kinds of things when boarding aircraft, and yes that includes children (although that's typically a deliberate abandonment). So while unusual to be certain, it's not actually outside the realm of possibility.
TL;DR
If it happened, the aircraft had likely just pushed back and so to return to the gate would require the tug (they wouldn't have started their engines yet) and thus ramp controller coordination.
If it didn't happen, someone went to a great deal of work (including research into the minutiae of Saudia's flight schedule) to get the story just right and deserves credit for that.
My money says the video is authentic and the product of the ramp controller hearing the request, thinking to himself: 'I'm gonna go viral for this' grabbing his phone to record, asking the pilot to repeat his request - which frustrates the pilot - producing the exchange recorded.  A game of journalistic telephone then blew the situation up to ludicrous levels.

Yep, Im pretty sure you're right... but this is not an answer with anything like valid sources. Its just more speculation.

@Jamiec Note, top line. "Impossible to confirm to the degree requested."
